# error TS2740 Type 'DeepPartial<Quiz>[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Question': id, question, hasId, save, and 4 more

Tags: javascript, mysql, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I don't know how to fix this error. Does anyone know what I need to fix to get this code to work?

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { CreateQuestionDto } from './dto/create-question.dto';
import { Question } from './question.entity';
import { QuestionRepository } from './question.repository';

@Injectable()
export class QuestionService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(QuestionRepository)
    private questionRepository: QuestionRepository,
  ) {}

  async createQuestion(question: CreateQuestionDto): Promise<Question> {
    return await this.questionRepository.save(question);
  }
}
```

Returns the following error:

src/modules/quiz/question.service.ts:15:5 - error TS2740: Type 'DeepPartial[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Question': id, question, hasId, save, and 4 more.

15     return await this.questionRepository.save(question);
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

src/modules/quiz/question.service.ts:15:47 - error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
Overload 1 of 4, '(entities: DeepPartial[], options?: SaveOptions): Promise<(DeepPartial & Quiz)[]>', gave the following error.
Argument of type 'CreateQuestionDto' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DeepPartial[]'.
Type 'CreateQuestionDto' is missing the following properties from type 'DeepPartial[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 29 more.
Overload 2 of 4, '(entity: DeepPartial, options?: SaveOptions): Promise<DeepPartial & Quiz>', gave the following error.
Type 'CreateQuestionDto' has no properties in common with type 'DeepPartial'.

15     return await this.questionRepository.save(question);

Question entity:

```
import { BaseEntity, Column, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity('questions')
export class Question extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: string;

  @Column({
    type: 'varchar',
  })
  question: string;
}
```

Question repository:

```
import { EntityRepository, Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { Quiz } from './quiz.entity';

@EntityRepository(Quiz)
export class QuestionRepository extends Repository<Quiz> {}
```

CreateQuestion dto:

```
import { IsNotEmpty, Length } from 'class-validator';

export class CreateQuestionDto {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @Length(3, 255)
  question: string;
}
```

Question repository:

```
import { EntityRepository, Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { Quiz } from './quiz.entity';

@EntityRepository(Quiz)
export class QuestionRepository extends Repository<Quiz> {}
```

Comment: Can you provide more info?, like the Question entity and the Question repository?

Comment: Yes I added the Question entity and question repository code.

Comment: @alejandroBarone

Comment: Do you need to extend the `BaseEntity`?. Also does `CreateQuestionDto` have all the properties that `Question extends BaseEntity` has?. Can you provide what `CreateQuestionDto` is?

Comment: @AlejandroBarone The tutorial I was watching extended the base entity with no problems. I added the createQuestionDto for you to look at.

Comment: It can be a bug from typeorm. Can you cast it to `any` to see if it works? `return await this.questionRepository.save(question as any);`

Comment: @AlejandroBarone I did that and now I get this error: [Nest] 26116  - 01/11/2022, 12:42:51 PM   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the QuestionService (?). Please make sure that the argument QuestionRepository at index [0] is available in the QuizModule context.

Comment: Did you change the arguments on the QuestionService?. I meant just in the function call
`async createQuestion(question: CreateQuestionDto): Promise<Question> { return await this.questionRepository.save(question as any); } `

Comment: I used `import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { CreateQuestionDto } from './dto/create-question.dto';
import { Question } from './question.entity';
import { QuestionRepository } from './question.repository';

@Injectable()
export class QuestionService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(QuestionRepository)
    private questionRepository: QuestionRepository,
  ) {}

  async createQuestion(question: CreateQuestionDto): Promise<Question> {
    return await this.questionRepository.save(question as any);
  }
}`

Comment: @AlejandroBarone

Comment: Did you add the service as a provider on the `QuizModule`?. You need to import the QuestionRepository and add the QuestionService as a provider 
`imports: [ TypeOrmModule.forFeature([QuestionRepository]) ]` and `providers: [QuestionService]`

Comment: @AlejandroBarone I just added it and I still am getting the errors that I got initially.

Comment: With the adittion on the module and the “as any” clause it throws the same error?. Can you provide a sample repo/code with all this for best assitance?

Comment: @AlejandroBarone With the as any it works. I'll include the repository code above.

Comment: Perfect!, so now it works. What about if you cast it as `Question`? instead of any?

Comment: @AlejandroBarone When I cast it as `Question` I get the same errors as before.

Comment: As I mentioned above, can you please provide a code-sandbox or a repo to help you futher?. Or does the `any` is enough?

Comment: @AlejandroBarone Here is the link to the repo https://github.com/Paulopearce/quiz/tree/master/server/src/modules/quiz

Comment: Please test the answer I posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `QuestionRepository` is pointing to another entity (`Quiz`).

Change it to:

```
export class QuestionRepository extends Repository<Question> {}
```

That way you can avoid the `any` clause and use the dto directly on the `save` call.

```
  async createQuestion(question: CreateQuestionDto): Promise<Question> {
    return await this.questionRepository.save(question);
  }
```

Comment: That was the issue. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Awesome. Can you please accept my answer on the check button and upvote it if you want?